# How to run multiple videos simultaneously in python using OpenCV, multi threading, queues?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, opencv, multiprocessing

I am trying to run two videos simultaneously using opencv, MultiThreading and Queues. However, both the queues gets filled with frames but the video does not run simultaneously, but one after another. Is there any way that we can make multiple videos simultaneously using queues with Multithreading or MultiProcessing?

```
import os
import threading
import queue as Queue
import cv2

video_path_1 = '/home/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
video_path_2 = '/home/cup.mp4'




class MyThread (threading.Thread):
    maxRetries = 22


def __init__(self, thread_id, name, video_url, thread_lock):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.thread_id = thread_id
    self.name = name
    self.video_url = video_url
    self.thread_lock = thread_lock
    self.Q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=128)



def run(self):
    print("Starting " + self.name)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_url)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            self.Q.put(frame)

def view(self):
    print('start view')
    while self.Q.qsize()>0:
        print('true')
        cv2.imshow('self.1', self.Q.get())
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print('false')

def main():

thread_lock = threading.Lock()
thread1 = MyThread(1, "Thread 1", video_path_1, thread_lock)
thread2 = MyThread(2, "Thread 2", video_path_2, thread_lock)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
cv2.imshow('1', thread2.Q.get())
cv2.imshow('23', thread1.Q.get())
print("Exiting Main Thread")

thread1.view()
thread2.view()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using queues instead of directly playing the video?

Comment: Filling the frames in a queue reduces the latency. So now I already I have frames loaded to perform object detection plus this can let me run two videos at once..

Answer (score 0):

Was working on playing segmented frames of the same video at the same time which I have not but here's some multiprocessing where I play multiple videos at the same time.

```py
import multiprocessing
import cv2

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def play_video(video, name):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if frame is None:
            continue
        if ret is False:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cap.release()
            break
        cv2.imshow(name, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
    cap.release()


videos = ["/Videos/samples/obamas.mp4", "/Videos/samples/testvideo.mp4"]

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
    [executor.submit(play_video, i, str(i))for i in videos]
```